# Why does Ember installs everything as devDependencies instead of normal dependency

Tags: javascript, ember.js, npm, ember-cli, package.json

Ember CLI applications have a package.json that lists everything as a dev dependency. Even stuff that is needed in the app's production version. For instance packages like ember and ember-data are installed as devdependencies.

As a reference, here's a sample of what I'm talking about: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/master/package.json#L17-L38

What's the reason for this?

Comment: So that you as a developer could choose what would be the real package that would be dealing with those dependencies? In case it is a real dependency for you, you should add those packages as a dependency for your own package.json

Comment: Because they are not needed after the build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In the context of application:**

As @Lux mentioned in the comments, you don't need them after the build.

The output of the application is the **build**, that is supposed to be the final product. Further, you generally don't depend on another application. You generally depend on a package or an addon.

**In the context of addons:**

I think there is an opinion to display all of the addon dependencies of an application at the application's `package.json` file. By doing this way, you can prevent that an addon unintentially adds a js file to the build.

As a result, the ember way of managing dependencies is to leave all of your dependencies at your `devDependencies` and add all of the dependencies of the addon to the application's `package.json` with default blueprints. So the end user can tune them.

Comment: If you create an addon the ember CLI will initially complain. Telling you to change the package.json similar to this: "dependencies": {"ember-cli-babel": "^6.8.2", "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.3"}, "devDependencies": {...